# Registration system based on JSP with MySQL connection - null's in db

Tags: mysql, web-services, jsp, jdbc, user-registration

i'm trying to create a registration system using jsp, beans and servlets. Registration process seems to be ok, but everytime data is supposed to be stored into database, rows are only filled with NULLs. Im a newbie in this subject so i would really apreciate your help!
Here is the code of this "system":

ragister.html

```
<html>
<body >
<form action="/Ragis/proces.jsp" method=post>
<center>
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1 border="1" bgcolor="lightblue">
<th bgcolor="lightblue" colspan=2>
<font size=5>User Registration</font>
<br>
<font size=2 color="red"><sup>*</sup> Required Fields</font>
</th>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top> 
<b>First Name<sup>*</sup></b> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="" size=20 maxlength=20></td>
<td  valign=top>
<b>Last Name<sup>*</sup></b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="lastName" value="" size=15 maxlength=20></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<b>E-Mail<sup>*</sup></b> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size=25  maxlength=125>
<br></td>
<td  valign=top>
<b>Cell Nr(9 fig.)<sup>*</sup></b> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="" size=10  maxlength=9></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top colspan=2>
<b>User Name<sup>*</sup></b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="userName" size=20 value=""  maxlength=10>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<b>Password<sup>*</sup></b> 
<br>
<input type="password" name="password1" size=10 value="" maxlength=10></td>
<td  valign=top>
<b>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup></b>
<br>
<input type="password" name="password2" size=10 value="" maxlength=10></td>
<br>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td  align=center colspan=2>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset"  
value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

proces.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%! 

%>
<jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="test.FormBean" scope="request">
<jsp:setProperty name="formHandler" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>
 <%   if (formHandler.validate()) {   
%>

<html>
<body>
<center>
<form action="/Ragis/Registration" method=post>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;"/>
    </form>

<table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border="1" >
<th bgcolor="lightblue" colspan=2>
<font size=5>Almost done! Just press SUBMIT to finish the registration procedure!</font>
</th>
<font size=4>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top> 
<b>First Name</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="firstName"/>
</td>
<td valign=top>
<b>Last Name</b>
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="lastName"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<b>E-Mail</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="email"/>
<br></td>
<td valign=top>
<b>Cell Nr(9 fig.)</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="zip"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top colspan=2>
<b>User Name</b>
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="userName"/>
</td>
</tr>
</font>
</table>
</center>
    </body>
    </html>
<%
   }  else {
%>
    <jsp:forward page="retry.jsp"/>
<%
   }
%>
```

retry.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="test.FormBean" scope="request"/>
<html> 
<body>
<form action="/Ragis/proces.jsp" method=post>
<center>
<table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=2 border=0>
<th bgcolor="lightblue" colspan=2>
<font size=5>User Registration</font>
<br>
<font size=2 color="red"><sup>*</sup> Required Fields </font>
</th>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top> 
<B>First Name<sup>*</sup></B> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="firstName" 
value='<%=formHandler.getFirstName()%>' size=15 maxlength=20>
<br><font size=2 
color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("firstName")%></font>
</td>
<td  valign=top>
<B>Last Name<sup>*</sup></B>
<br>
<input type="text" name="lastName" 
value='<%=formHandler.getLastName()%>' size=15 maxlength=20>
<br><font size=2 
color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("lastName")%></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<B>E-Mail<sup>*</sup></B> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value='<%=formHandler.getEmail()%>' 
size=25  maxlength=125>
<br><font size=2 color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("email")%></font>
</td>
<td  valign=top>
<B>Cell Nr(9 fig.)<sup>*</sup></B> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="zip" value='<%=formHandler.getZip()%>' size=5  
maxlength=9>
<br><font size=2 color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("zip")%></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top colspan=2> 
<B>User Name<sup>*</sup></B>
<br>
<input type="text" name="userName" size=10 
value='<%=formHandler.getUserName()%>'  maxlength=10>
<br><font size=2 
color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("userName")%></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<B>Password<sup>*</sup></B> 
<br>
<input type="password" name="password1" size=10 
value='<%=formHandler.getPassword1()%>'  maxlength=10>
<br><font size=2 
color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("password1")%></font>
</td>
<td  valign=top>
<B>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup></B>
<br>
<input type="password" name="password2" size=10 
value='<%=formHandler.getPassword2()%>'  maxlength=10>
<br><font size=2 
color=red><%=formHandler.getErrorMsg("password2")%></font>
</td>
<br>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td colspan=2 align=center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

FormBean.java

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FormBean {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String email;
      private String userName;
      private String password1;
      private String password2;
      private String zip;
      private String notify;
      private Hashtable errors;
      public boolean validate() {
        boolean bool=true;
        if (firstName.equals("")) {
          errors.put("firstName","Please enter your first name");
          firstName="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (lastName.equals("")) {
          errors.put("lastName","Please enter your last name");
          lastName="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (email.equals("") || (email.indexOf('@') == -1)) {
          errors.put("email","Please enter a valid email address");
          email="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (userName.equals("")) {
          errors.put("userName","Please enter a username");
          userName="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (password1.equals("") ) {
          errors.put("password1","Please enter a valid password");
          password1="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (!password1.equals("") && (password2.equals("") || 
            !password1.equals(password2))) {
          errors.put("password2","Please confirm your password");
          password2="";
          bool=false;
        }
        if (zip.equals("") || zip.length() !=9 ) {
          errors.put("zip","Please enter a valid cell number");
          zip="";
          bool=false;
        } else {
          try {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(zip);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            errors.put("zip","Please enter a valid cell number");
            zip="";
            bool=false;
          }
        }
        return bool;
      }
      public String getErrorMsg(String s) {
        String errorMsg =(String)errors.get(s.trim());
        return (errorMsg == null) ? "":errorMsg;
      }
      public FormBean() {
        firstName="";
        lastName="";
        email="";
        userName="";
        password1="";
        password2="";
        zip="";
        notify="";
        errors = new Hashtable();
      }
      public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
      }
      public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
      }
      public String getEmail() {
        return email;
      }
      public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
      }
      public String getPassword1() {
        return password1;
      }
      public String getPassword2() {
        return password2;
      }
      public String getZip() {
        return zip;
      }
      public String getNotify() {
        return notify;
      }
      public void setFirstName(String fname) {
        firstName =fname;
      }
      public void setLastName(String lname) {
        lastName =lname;
      }
      public void setEmail(String eml) {
        email=eml;
      }
      public void setUserName(String u) {
        userName=u;
      }
      public void  setPassword1(String p1) {
        password1=p1;
      }
      public void  setPassword2(String p2) {
        password2=p2;
      }
      public void setZip(String z) {
        zip=z;
      }
      public void setErrors(String key, String msg) {
        errors.put(key,msg);
      }
      public void setNotify(String n) {
        notify=n;
      }
    }
```

Registration.java

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Registration extends HttpServlet{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
super.init(config);
}
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
throws ServletException, IOException{
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp";
Connection connection=null;
ResultSet rs;
res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
String firstNamed = req.getParameter("firstName");
String lastNamed = req.getParameter("lastName");
String emaild = req.getParameter("email");
String userNamed = req.getParameter("userName");
String password1d = req.getParameter("password1");
String zipd = req.getParameter("zip");
String auto = "u";
try {
Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root"); 
String sql = "insert into userprofile values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, firstNamed);
pst.setString(2, lastNamed);
pst.setString(3, emaild);
pst.setString(4,userNamed);
pst.setString(5, password1d);
pst.setString(6, zipd);
pst.setString(7, auto);

int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
out.println(" Welcome : ");
out.println(" '"+userNamed+"'");
pst.close();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch(SQLException e){
out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch (Exception e){
out.println(e);
}
finally {

try {
if (connection != null) connection.close();
}
catch (SQLException ignored){
out.println(ignored);
}
}
}
}
```

Briefly: ragister.html -> proces.jsp, if all info valid -> Registration.java with sending data to db, else retry.jsp with error description till everything is ok.
It seems to work preety fine, but in database i get a table with row filled with nulls :(

Probably i made mistake trying to read data in Registration.java.
Please, please help me and sory if i am unclear anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to submit a blank form.

```
<form action="/Ragis/Registration" method=post>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;"/>
    </form>
```

There is no textfield within this form. First correct this.

Comment: yep its the only problem here. could you tell me what should I write to do so? I tried many things but i cant figure it out... Just to send this params to servlet

Comment: put
`<input type="text" name="zip" value="" size=10  maxlength=9>` and other textfields within the form as 

`<form action="/Ragis/Registration" method=post>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="" size=10  maxlength=9>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;"/>
    </form>`

Comment: but i dont want to type the data again, just to get all params from bean, from jsp to servlet

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved. bean dissapears after quiting jsp file, so i had to get atributes from it and assign to FormBean variable. so proces.jsp should look like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="test.FormBean" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%! 

%>
<jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="test.FormBean" scope="request">
<jsp:setProperty name="formHandler" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>
 <% 

 FormBean x = (FormBean)request.getAttribute("formHandler");

 if (formHandler.validate())
 {   
%>

<html>
<body>
<center>
<form action="/Ragis/Registration" method=post>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
<%request.setAttribute("bean",x) ;
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Registration");
view.forward(request, response);
%>
</input>
</form>


<table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border="1" >
<th bgcolor="lightblue" colspan=2>
<font size=5>Almost done! Just press SUBMIT to finish the registration procedure!</font>
</th>
<font size=4>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top> 
<b>First Name</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="firstName"/>
</td>
<td valign=top>
<b>Last Name</b>
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="lastName"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top>
<b>E-Mail</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="email"/>
<br></td>
<td valign=top>
<b>Cell Nr(9 fig.)</b> 
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="zip"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="lightblue">
<td valign=top colspan=2>
<b>User Name</b>
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="formHandler" property="userName"/>
</td>
</tr>
</font>
</table>
</center>
    </body>
    </html>
<%
   }  else {
%>
    <jsp:forward page="retry.jsp"/>
<%
   }
%>
```

Project runs well on jBoss 4.2

**Thanks XCoder for quick and good diagnosis! ;)**